# Taylor series expansion doubt

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, taylor-expansion

Employ taylor series method to obtain correct to four places of decimals, solution of the D.E with dy/dx =$x^2$ +$y^2$ with y=0 when x=0 for x=0.4

Solution: y'=$x^2$ +$y^2$

```
       y"=2x+2yy'  and so on
```

I dont understand how to evaluate (differentiate) y to get those y', y" and all. I am not able to figure out.

For e.g http://www.papersolutions.in/ans.php?sem=sem2&img=ans10&s=&m=may&y=13

I am not able to differentiate y, if possible kindly explain step by step execution.

Comment: I'm confused by the words "$x = 0$ for $x = 0.4$."

Comment: @EricTowers See other question of the same type in the link provided.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the Picard iteration,
$$
y_{n+1}(x)=0+\int_0^x(t^2+y_n(t)^2)\,dt
=\frac13x^3+\int_0^xy_n(t)^2\,dt
$$
Start with $y_0=0$ to get $y_1(x)=\frac13x^3$, insert to get
$$
y_2(x)=\frac13x^3+\int_0^x\frac19t^6\,dt=\frac13x^3+\frac1{63}x^7
$$
which is precise up to $O(x^{11})$, and so on.

But already the term $\frac1{63}(0.4)^7\simeq 2.6·10^{-5}$ is below your error threshold.

Answer (score 1):

You must use the rules for differentiating a composite function:
$$
y''(x)=D(x^2+y(x)^2)=D(x^2)+D(y(x)^2)=2x + 2 y(x)D(y(x))=2x+2y(x)y'(x),
$$
and so on.

Comment: How is this different from what the OP has written?

Comment: It is not easy to guess what the OP needs. He wrote "I dont understand how to evaluate (differentiate) y to get those y', y" and all" so I presumed he was at pains with differentiating y'. I may be wrong, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You have \begin{align*}
    y' &= x^2 + y^2  \\
    y'' &= 2x + 2 y y'
\end{align*}
so you have
$$  y'' = 2x + 2y(x^2+y^2)  \text{,}  $$
i.e., you use your earlier equations to eliminate the $y'$, $y''$, et c. terms from the right-hand sides.